# 2 buttons with the same action

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, placement

I'm currently working on a project, and the FE devs pointed out that I had the same action twice in a page, and I knew I had done this, but after researching more about it, there's not much I can find.

For context, I have a side menu (sort of like a dashboard), in the side menu the user can "add user" (this is a tertiary button) and while in the "Users" overview page that appears on the right of this menu, the user can also "add user" (primary button), but the user can be in another page and still "add user" through the side menu. Am I overcomplicating? Should I reduce it to one button?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @AdamSilver added

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid having the same action twice on the page until research shows that it’s necessary (which is almost never).

In your case it’s because you have sidebar which seems to duplicate the content in the main part of the page.

If I was in your position, I’d look to have 1 single column.

Something a bit like this (you may not need the filter on the left):

[image]

Comment: It can duplicate it, but not always, everything can be closed into the roles. So do you think I should keep the primary button on the main page or the tertiary on the side menu? 
The reason the side menu is designed like this is because eventually the platform will have a lot of users and a lot of roles, so role management is going to be pretty chaotic. So my idea was to keep a bit of the old system (buttons on the side menu), but add primary buttons and actions to where they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout structure is similar to that of UXSE (this page) from which you can take the example to follow:

- The <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button is unique
- Always stay in the top right corner
- The sidebar only allows browsing the following sections
- The <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button only appears in the sections where
  it is pertinent and keeping the same location (eg: Unanswered or
  Home)

On the other side, the repetition of CTA buttons usually indicates a persuasive action which is not the case that you indicate in your description. For example, e-commerce usually repeats the shopping cart button to tempt the user to carry out the action: BUY.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Indeed this seemed to be what made more since upon reviewing everything. But I still wanted some opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could replace "Add user" and "Add role" with something like "Manage users" which opens up the page on the right.

This would allow you to keep the "Add user" CTA in one place (on the main page) and still provide a path for people to edit (add users etc).